# How to isolate dictionary data in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created database of different payments in different departments:

```
paymentType={"Cash":0,"Amex":0,"All Other Cards":0}
departments={"Lounge":0,"MBar":0,"Resto":0,"TBar":0,"TFloor":0,"Events":0}
for dep in departments.keys():
    data=paymentType
    departments[dep]=data
```

however, when I assign value to one of “paymentType” in specific department

```
departments["Lounge"]["Cash"]=8
```

it changes “Cash” value in all “departments”

I would like to keep ability to assign value by string, thats why I didnt use class.

Comment: Because you've assigned the **same dictionary** to every key in the `departments` dictionary.

Comment: Can I assign new entity of same dictionary ? To speed up process, so I dont have to repeat same code.

Comment: Yes, by using `paymentType.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

`data=paymentType.copy()`

otherwise you assign the same dictionary to all fields.